# Correct way to create shareable module (package imports)

Tags: python, pandas, module

I want to create a module that I will share with others however I am quite new to this and am having issues with the final step of tidying it up for other's use. Imagine it is called something like `my_module.py` and looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

def function_1(a,b):
    return a*b

def function_2(c,d):
    return pd.DataFrame(data=c,columns=d)
```

I want this to be able to be imported by someone else, so that they can use the underlying functions like:

```
my_module.function_1(a=5,b=2)
```

and so on. However, if I do `import my_module` then `my_module.pd` also appears in the autocomplete (as in the `pandas` import that `my_module.py` made).

This seems like terrible practice to me. So, what is the correct way to load these imports?

Ideally, this would be shareable so that someone could install it the way someone would install a stats module. I'm fine if the solution is just some kind of thing that checks to make sure things are imported in certain ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with what you are doing. Your module **requires** `pandas` so you must import it. PEP8 specifies imports should go at the top, not nested within the functions. Doing this will add it as an attribute when you then `import my_module`. Because you are building upon `pandas` you cannot just share your module, you also need to share `pandas` (or check that they already have `pandas` installed with the correct or sufficient version).

Still, it might be overkill to import the entire `pandas` library when you have a single function that only uses the `DataFrame` class. In that case you can do:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

def function_1(a,b):
    return a*b

def function_2(c,d):
    return DataFrame(data=c,columns=d)
```

Now `my_module` will only have the `.DataFrame` class attached to it, not the entire `pandas` library. If you do wind up using more and more of the `pandas` library in your module, then importing separate parts is more of a nuisance, so just import `pandas`.

And to use `pandas` as an example, it's built upon `numpy`. Underlying every DataFrame is a `numpy.ndarray` so you may not have noticed it, but `numpy` is there:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.np?

Type:        module
String form: <module 'numpy' from 'c:\\program files\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py'>
File:        c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py
Docstring:  
NumPy
=====
```

---

You can make it much more difficult to access the `pandas` attribute, but you need to reorganize how you distribute your Library. Let's say you want to share a library called `MyLibrary` which could be composed of several modules (that we will put with the module folder). They could each have their own functions, with names that should not overlap which we will need to import in a separate python script (`api.py`). Then you would do:

```
MyLibrary/
    __init__.py
    modules/
        MyModule1.py
        api.py
```

where we have the files:

#### __init__.py

```
from MyLibrary.modules.api import *
```

#### api.py

```
from MyLibrary.modules.MyModule1 import function_1, function_2
```

#### MyModule1.py

```
import pandas as pd

def function_1(a,b):
    return a*b

def function_2(c,d):
    return pd.DataFrame(data=c,columns=d)
```

Now we have access to the functions, but `pd` is no longer there:

```
import MyLibrary

MyLibrary.function_2([1], ['a'])
#   a
#0  1

MyLibrary.pd
#AttributeError: module 'MyLibrary' has no attribute 'pd'
```

To be fair, `pd` is there, it's just hidden away much further down in `MyLibrary.modules.MyModule1.pd`. But then again, `pandas` has `numpy` everywhere. It's in `pd.core.reshape.concat.np`, `pd.core.reshape.merge.np`, `pd.core.common.np` and really almost every file, you cannot avoid it.

Comment: This is really excellent and definitely worked though it seems very sneaky. Is this considered best practice by people who write professional type stats packages to hide imports in their code?

Comment: @LucasH not sure about best practice, but it seems to be how [`pandas`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/tree/v0.24.1/pandas) decided to organize the code, at least with my level of understanding. There are a lot of benefits with this, namely that everything is under a single name `MyLibrary` instead of needing to `import Module1 as mod1`, `import Module2 as mod2`, and you control exactly what functions get attached at the first level attribute. Everything is always still there, but nested so you can have more organized attributes.